# Speed up AWS PostgreSQL insertion via Python script

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws, python

I have 120,000 csv inside my AWS EC2 instance, each containing 120,000 rows. I can't insert each of them as is into my AWS RDS postgresql DB, that will be 120,000^2 = 14,400,000,000 records. Each csv is about 2 MB.

My approach is:

- Python script that converts 120,000 records into just 1 record (list of dictionary) for each csv (now 5 MB after condensing the data) with the help of `pandas` library
- The python script then insert each csv's 1 record into AWS postgresql database via `pandas.to_sql` (which uses `sqlalchemy`
- I use python multiprocessing module to fully utilize my AWS EC2 to speed up data insertion
- I did not create additional indexes in order to speed up my data insertion
- I use AWS EC2 instance with up to 25GB of network connection

My observation is:

- At the beginning, my code will insert 50 csv per min, which is decent speed
- However, right now, with 50k csv being inserted, it only insert 1k csv in 5 hours, about 3.33 csv per min
- I tried using psql `\copy` and realized that it takes between 30-50 sec to insert 1 csv, that's slower than my script that converts the data and insert into the DB directly

I am not sure how I can speed up things up.

Comment: You've condensed each file from 2MB to 5MB?  What are the column types into which you are inserting this data?  What indexes exist?  What class of RDS machine is this?

Comment: The 5 MB file size is if I export the interim data into csv (which I don't do after I realized that `\copy` is not faster). The column type that I am inserting into is `jsonb` The only index is the default `id` column. This is just a `t2.micro` class, I check and see that the cpu usage is between 10 - 60% with my multiprocessing @jjanes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

t2 classes are unsuitable for high work loads, by design.  Once you have used up all your CPU credits, performance is abysmal.  Again, by design.

Don't use t2 (or any t*) instances if you care about performance.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to monitor the CPU credits on RDS (the way you can on EC2)

Comment: What instance class would you recommend I change to?

Comment: I don't know how intensively you will be using the database after it is populated.  I'd probably start out with db.m5.large.

Comment: Thanks, I change t2 into a different instance class as you suggested, and it works.